encoding issues in R
As part of a larger workflow, I need to extract unique character strings from a data frame. Suppose I have this data frame:
dummy <- structure(list(location = c("RD WEST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE", "RD NORTH - ACOUSTIC RELEASE", 
"RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE", "R SOUTHWEST REEF", "RD NORTH - ACOUSTIC RELEASE", 
"RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE", "RD WEST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE"
)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

# A tibble: 7 × 1
  location                   
  <chr>                      
1 RD WEST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE 
2 RD NORTH - ACOUSTIC RELEASE
3 RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE 
4 R SOUTHWEST REEF           
5 RD NORTH - ACOUSTIC RELEASE
6 RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE 
7 RD WEST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE 

You would think that if I run
unique(dummy$location)

R would output only 4 unique character strings but instead it returns all of them. After some digging I found that the culprit is the encoding. (No idea how/why this got messed up. I imported excel files directly from google drive into R.)
Encoding(dummy$location) 
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"  

I tried converting "unknown" decodings to "UTF-8" but none of my attempts seem to work. This is what I've tried:
dummy$location <- iconv(dummy$location, from = "unknown", to = "UTF-8")

Encoding(dummy$location) <- "UTF-8"

dummy$location <- enc2utf8(dummy$location)

library(stringi)
dummy$location <- stri_encode(dummy$location, "", "UTF-8")

Any insights and solutions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks
EDIT: In case this helps:
for (i in seq_along(test3$location)) {
  cat("String", i, ":", test3$location[i], "\n")
  print(charToRaw(test3$location[i]))
  cat("\n")
}

confirms that the bottom 3 character strings are not identical to the top 3:
String 1 : RD WEST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE 
 [1] 52 44 20 57 45 53 54 20 2d 20 41 43 4f 55 53 54 49 43 20 52 45 4c 45 41 53 45

String 2 : RD NORTH - ACOUSTIC RELEASE 
 [1] 52 44 20 4e 4f 52 54 48 20 2d 20 41 43 4f 55 53 54 49 43 20 52 45 4c 45 41 53 45

String 3 : RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE 
 [1] 52 44 20 45 41 53 54 20 2d 20 41 43 4f 55 53 54 49 43 20 52 45 4c 45 41 53 45

String 4 : R SOUTHWEST REEF 
 [1] 52 20 53 4f 55 54 48 57 45 53 54 20 52 45 45 46

String 5 : RD NORTH - ACOUSTIC RELEASE 
 [1] 52 44 c2 a0 4e 4f 52 54 48 20 2d c2 a0 41 43 4f 55 53 54 49 43 c2 a0 52 45 4c 45 41 53 45

String 6 : RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE 
 [1] 52 44 c2 a0 45 41 53 54 c2 a0 2d c2 a0 41 43 4f 55 53 54 49 43 c2 a0 52 45 4c 45 41 53 45

String 7 : RD WEST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE 
 [1] 52 44 c2 a0 57 45 53 54 c2 a0 2d c2 a0 41 43 4f 55 53 54 49 43 c2 a0 52 45 4c 45 41 53 45

EDIT2: The solution, based on Roland's suggestion:
install.packages("fedmatch")
library(fedmatch)
    
test3$location <- clean_strings(test3$location) # this sanitizes the strings
    
unique(dummy$location)
[1] "rd west acoustic release"  "rd north acoustic release" "rd east acoustic release" [4] "r southwest reef"      
    
Encoding(dummy$location)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"

I guess the "unknown" is okay then, as long as they're all the same.

I can't reproduce. I would suspect the culprit is the dash, which is probably different characters in your actual data (minus vs some type of dash character). Try sanitizing your strings.

You're right! when I tried running my above code in a new RStudio window I couldn't replicate either. However, your suggestion helped. If you pose this as a solution, I will credit you for it.

Your issue is that you have No-Break Space (NBSP), i.e. \U00a0 in your character vector. We can see that by reconstructing them from your raw character dump:
view_string <- function(x) {
    strtoi(x, base = 16L) |>
        as.raw() |>
        rawToChar() |>
        stringr::str_view()
}

east1 <- c("0x52", "0x44", "0x20", "0x45", "0x41", "0x53", "0x54", "0x20", "0x2d", "0x20", "0x41", "0x43", "0x4f", "0x55", "0x53", "0x54", "0x49", "0x43", "0x20", "0x52", "0x45", "0x4c", "0x45", "0x41", "0x53", "0x45")
east2 <- c("0x52", "0x44", "0xc2", "0xa0", "0x45", "0x41", "0x53", "0x54", "0xc2", "0xa0", "0x2d", "0xc2", "0xa0", "0x41", "0x43", "0x4f", "0x55", "0x53", "0x54", "0x49", "0x43", "0xc2", "0xa0", "0x52", "0x45", "0x4c", "0x45", "0x41", "0x53", "0x45")
view_string(east1)
# [1] │ RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE
view_string(east2)
# [1] │ RD{\u00a0}EAST{\u00a0}-{\u00a0}ACOUSTIC{\u00a0}RELEASE

So these strings are not identical. You can fix this by using the \h regex with perl = TRUE. The PCRE docs note:

The sequences \h, \H, \v, and \V are features that were added to Perl at release 5.10

These represent horizontal and vertical spaces, and their negation. \h captures 19 Unicode horizontal space characters, including NBSP:
dummy$location  <- gsub("\\h", " ", dummy$location, perl = TRUE) 
length(unique(dummy$location))
# [1] 4


Sure this could also be a solution. Thanks for sharing your insights.

If you start using constructive::construct() rather than dput you will spot these issues directly:
# for reproducibility
dummy <- data.frame(location = c(
  "RD WEST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE", 
  "RD NORTH - ACOUSTIC RELEASE", 
  "RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE",
  "R SOUTHWEST REEF", 
  "RD\U{A0}NORTH\U{A0}-\U{A0}ACOUSTIC\U{A0}RELEASE", 
  "RD\U{A0}EAST\U{A0}-\U{A0}ACOUSTIC\U{A0}RELEASE", 
  "RD\U{A0}WEST\U{A0}-\U{A0}ACOUSTIC\U{A0}RELEASE"
))

# what you were seeing
dummy
#>                      location
#> 1  RD WEST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE
#> 2 RD NORTH - ACOUSTIC RELEASE
#> 3  RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE
#> 4            R SOUTHWEST REEF
#> 5 RD NORTH - ACOUSTIC RELEASE
#> 6  RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE
#> 7  RD WEST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE

constructive::construct(dummy)
#> data.frame(
#>   location = c(
#>     "RD WEST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE", "RD NORTH - ACOUSTIC RELEASE",
#>     "RD EAST - ACOUSTIC RELEASE", "R SOUTHWEST REEF",
#>     "RD\U{A0}NORTH\U{A0}-\U{A0}ACOUSTIC\U{A0}RELEASE",
#>     "RD\U{A0}EAST\U{A0}-\U{A0}ACOUSTIC\U{A0}RELEASE",
#>     "RD\U{A0}WEST\U{A0}-\U{A0}ACOUSTIC\U{A0}RELEASE"
#>   )
#> )

Created on 2024-09-18 with reprex v2.1.0
The Encoding() output was giving away that the 3 last strings were not ASCII, so it could have been the dash, a non standard space, or other homoglyphs like Cyrillic A etc. {constructive} by default always shows the code of non ASCII characters.
Note that it was not an encoding issue, but an homoglyph issue.
